# Linear Combination of Bounded Pareto RVs

Tags: distributions, random-variable, pareto-distribution

I am working with bounded Pareto distributions and was wondering whether I can say anything about the distributions of linear combinations of Pareto RVs? Suppose the PDF

$f(x; \alpha_i, L_i, H_i) = \frac{\alpha_i L_i^{\alpha_i}x^{- \alpha_i - 1}}{1 - \left(\frac{L_i}{H_i} \right)^{\alpha_i}}$

where $\alpha$ is the shape parameter, $L$ is the lower bound, $H$ the upper bound, and $i = 1, 2, 3, ...$ an instance of a bounded Pareto. If I were to combine them in the following fashion, what can I say about the distribution of the result:

$g(x)= \sum_i^N f(x; \alpha_i, L_i, H_i) \beta_i$

with $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $N \in \mathbb{N}$. I would assume that the resulting distribution $g(x)$ would have the following bounds

$L = \sum_i^N \beta_i L_i$

$H = \sum_i^N \beta_i H_i$

Furthermore, I know that sums of "regular" (unbounded) Pareto RVs take on the the tail exponent $\alpha$ of the RV with the lowest $\alpha$. So in my case $\alpha = \min  \alpha_i$. I have tested that using simulations of the problem and then looking at Hill plots to get an estimate of the tail exponent and it also seems to hold for the bounded case. Am I right in my assumptions?

Comment: You can also state the mean of each and so the mean of the combination, and similarly with second moments and so the variance.

Comment: You mean that a moment of the combined RV is the same as the combined moments of the different RV?

Comment: That is the case for the mean by linearity of expectation, though a little more complicated for higher moments

Comment: For sure. Going via the moments is also another way. I was going for the parameters of the distribution.

Comment: I would be surprised if in general the combination was from the family of truncated Pareto distributions, so "parameters" may not be the correct word

Comment: I'm quite certain that it would have to be bounded and that the bounds are as described. Regarding the shape parameter, I did some testing and it seems to be robust and analogous to the unbounded case

Comment: Your specification of $g(x)$ as a linear combination of  probability density functions means you have a mixture distribution instead of a linear combination of independent random variables.  You need $\sum \beta_i =1$ for $g(x)$ to integrate to $1$ and the distribution will be bounded by $\min L_i$ and $\max H_i$.  What happens near the maximum depends on which $i$ maximises $H_i$ (it gets a little more complicated if they all have the same $H_i$ but different $\alpha_i$)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The resulting distribution might also be multimodal. I might just use the moments, given that I do not need the entire distribution. Found this paper, which describes it a little:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.01032.pdf